# Reverse Proxy with Azure Websites

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy

I have one web app hosted in Azure websites. I am consuming API from another level (having method PUT, POST, GET, DELETE).. I want to make my web app compatible with IE8 and IE9 but unfortunately, it does not support CORS for PUT, DELETE even with XDomainRequest patch.

Now, I want to use something like Reverse proxy so that it will think the request is from same domain. Probably Reverse Proxy

Is it possible in Azure Website? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the way of doing it myself :-)

I achieved it using Rewrite Module and ARR.

Here is outline of what I did -

- Install ARR and URL Rewrite modules using Web Platform Installer
- Enable Proxy Settings from IIS -> Application Request Routing (ARR) -> Server Proxy Settings (On Right Pane)
- Add Web app to Sites
- Open Web.config of an app and add following inside `<system.webServer> </system.webServer>`

  `<rewrite> 
          <rules> 
              <rule name="Route Requests from localhost api to Remote API url" stopProcessing="true"> 
                  <match url="^api/(.*)" /> 
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" /> 
                  </conditions> 
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.remotedomain.com/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                  <serverVariables>
                      <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" /> 
                  </serverVariables> 
              </rule> 
          </rules> 
          <outboundRules> 
              <rule name="Convert remote API response to localhost API" preCondition="ResponseIsHtmlOrJSON"> 
                  <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^http(s)?://www.remotedomain.com/api/(.*)" /> 
                  <action type="Rewrite" value="api/{R:2}" /> 
              </rule> 
              <preConditions> 
                  <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtmlOrJSON">
                      <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                      <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/json" /> 
                  </preCondition> 
              </preConditions> 
          </outboundRules> 
      </rewrite>`
- Add server variables to avoid Gzip blocking from IIS

Basically, this will add a rewrite rules (inbound and outbound).

1. Inbound rule will route all the requests to `http://localhost/api/{API_PATH}` to `https://www.remotedomain.com/api/{API_PATH}`
2. Outbound rule will map all the response coming from remote API (`https://www.remotedomain.com/api/`) to dummy API url `http://localhost/api`. So the browser will assume the request being sent and response coming back is from local API itself.

I blogged the detailed tutorial here : http://www.wrapcode.com/infrastructure/configure-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-and-arr-for-iis/